# Convert AES encrypted hex string back to string in C++

Tags: c++, c, character, aes, printf

In C++, I have an AES-encrypted char* which I transform to its HEX representation before sending it as an URL parameter, [just as it is done in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501803/convert-aes-encrypted-string-to-hex-in-c). Now, I want to do the opposite, that is converting such hex back to char* again. However I am puzzled here - using the sprintf with either %x or %s would result in a totally different value. How could I convert it back again? Thanks...

Comment: What have you tried? You could allocate a buffer of size strlen(hex)/2, and then traverse the string, parsing pairs of digits back into a char with sscanf and storing it in the right place in the buffer. Maybe try that, then show us your code so far if you can't get it to work.

Comment: The inverse of `sprintf` is `sscanf`, not another `sprintf`. In other words - you are READING something, not WRITING it. In `sscanf` the format string says "starting from this string, using this format, find this value". Can you figure it out from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sscanf()` like this:

```
#define LEN  16 /* 128/8 */

void aes_to_char(char *aes, char *res)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
    sscanf(aes, "%2hhx", &res[i]);
    aes += 2;
  }
}
```

`"%2hhx"` means "a 2-chars hexadecimal value, to be stored in a `char *`.